# UITapGestureRecognizer in UICollectionViewCell for UIImageView does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to put a UITapGestureRecognizer on UIImageView in UICollectionViewCell but it does not work. Here is the code:

```
class ImageGalleryCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!
    let uniqueTag = String.random()
    func setup(){
        let rec = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(rec)
    }
    @objc func tap(){
        print("tap")
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably forgot to set the image view's `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`.

Comment: where you call setup

Comment: I call setup in     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell and I set isUserInteractionEnabled

Comment: Unless you show enough code to allow us to reproduce the problem and explain exactly what goes wrong, we cannot help further. You are just asking for guesses! That's not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code snippet you provide, it seems that you should manually set the image view [`isUserInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621063-isuserinteractionenabled) property to `true` -since it is `false` by default-, in `setup`:

```
func setup(){
    let rec = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
    // here we go:
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(rec)
}
```

Also, I would suggest to call `setup` method in the cell class itself, in the [`awakeFromNib()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib) instead of calling it in the view controller - [`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview) (or any method in the view controller layer), simply like this:

```
class ImageGalleryCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!
    //let uniqueTag = String.random()
    func setup(){
        let rec = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        // here we go:
        imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(rec)
    }
    @objc func tap(){
        print("tap")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setup()
    }
}
```

That's because such a behavior should be setup only for one time when delivering the cell but not each time it has been shown.

Comment: imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true - I have already added it, but it still does not work

Comment: @WorieN then add some breakpoints to make sure that the code is even reachable, thus detecting what's the exact reason of the issue.